# Vimtex not opening SumatraPDF automatically

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-vim-latex

I am using Vim 64 bit and have installed Vimtex on Windows 11. I can compile a LaTeX file and changes are shown in the pdf file, but typing  `\lv` does not open my pdf viewer, SumatraPDF.

Here is part of my `_vimrc` file:

```
 let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = 'pdf'
 let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode $*'
 let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = 'SumatraPDF -reuse-instance'
```

I have tried changing `letg:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = 'C:\path\to\SumatraPDF -reuse-instance'` and have added SumatraPDF to my PATH.

Here is my latexmk output when I run `\lo`

```
Win CP console initial and current in/out Win: (437, 437), (1252, 1252)
Coding system for system and terminal: 'CP1252'
---
Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 17 Mar. 2022. Version 4.77, version: 4.77.
======= Need to update make_preview_continuous for target files
Not using a previewer
------------
Running 'echo vimtex_compiler_callback_compiling'
------------
vimtex_compiler_callback_compiling
Latexmk: Nothing to do for 'testing.tex'.
Latexmk: All targets (testing.pdf) are up-to-date
------------
Running 'echo vimtex_compiler_callback_success'
------------
vimtex_compiler_callback_success
Win CP console initial and current in/out Win: (437, 437), (1252, 1252)
Coding system for system and terminal: 'CP1252'
---
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: The settings you are discussing are **not** relevant to VimTeX. They are settings for [LaTeX-Suite](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/). Thus, changing these options will have _no_ effect on VimTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Using Sumatra

Figured out what the problem was. I replaced everything I used before to:

```
"Only works if let g:vimtex_view_general_viewer= path\to\sumatrapdf.exe
let g:vimtex_view_general_viewer = 'C:\Users\Pranav\AppData\Local\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe'
let g:vimtex_view_general_options
                \ = '-reuse-instance -forward-search @tex @line @pdf'
```

To enable double click in the PDF to go to that spot in the LaTeX file:

1. Go to Sumatra PDF --> Settings --> Options
2. Paste `cmd /c start /min "" vim -v --not-a-term -T dumb -c "VimtexInverseSearch %l '%f'"` into *Set inverse search command-line*
3. For more info, use the command `:vimtex-synctex-inverse-search`

Thanks to @Karl Yngve Lervåg for pointing out that my original settings worked for LaTeX-Suite and not Vimtex + showing where the documentation is!

Comment: The settings you are discussing are **not** relevant to VimTeX. They are settings for [LaTeX-Suite](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/). Thus, changing these options will have _no_ effect on VimTeX.

Comment: If you find that changing these options indeed _have_ an effect, then you are clearly using LaTeX-Suite and not VimTeX. You should update your question and answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi, I am using Vimtex. Maybe because I was using LaTeX-Suite settings it didn't work. Updating my answer to my current settings that work with Vimtex

Comment: Ok, it is an improvement. But now you are using configuration you find in old issue threads (the last comment in issue 627 is from december 2016, which is more than 5 years ago now). What you want is to read the documentation where this is all explained! Please read `:help vimtex-view-sumatrapdf`.

Comment: I read the documentation and will update the answer. I started using Vim last week, so I appreciate your help!

Comment: No problem; glad to help! Now it seems you're answer is quite good, so I'll upvote it :)